# Ehcache-Spring-Annotations: How to get cache manager reference?

Tags: spring, ehcache

I am using **ehcache-spring-annotations** to cache my application data. For this, I have below configuration:

```
<bean id="ehCacheManager"
      class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean" > 
      <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:ehcache.xml"/>
     </bean>      
    <ehcache:annotation-driven cache-manager="ehCacheManager" />
```

I want to get the reference of '**net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager**' out of configured bean '**ehCacheManager**'. So that, I can manually perform put or remove operations directly in cache using 'CacheManager'.

Any way to get reference of '**net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager**' out of '**org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean**'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used below code to get the cache manager reference in my class:

```
@Resource
private CacheManager ehCacheManager;
```